# Add language pack for anysoftkeboard

Tags: android-softkeyboard

I'm now trying to add a new language for Anysoftkeyboard.
But I don't quite sure how create a language wordlist and make it a language package for Anysoftkeyboard.
I'm now creating a Binary Dictionaries as this [URL](https://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/BinaryDictionaries) but don't know what the next step is.

Could anyone be so kind to tell me the steps of add a new language to AnysoftKeyboard?
Besides I download the database from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database.) and what I trying to add is Chinese and Vietnamese.

Other method for making a Android softkeyboard is also appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your codes worked so far ?

Comment: I download word-lists from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database and generate word-list from https://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/BinaryDictionaries,then convert the wordlist to binarydictionary(.mp3). After that I simply put the .mp3 file named as binary.mp3 to the \assets folder of template code from here http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/downloads/detail?name=AnySoftKeyboardLanguagePackTemplate_5.zip&can=2&q=               But it just doesn't work. Is there any mistake?

Comment: doesn't work is not a valid problem description. Any error ?

Comment: oh,sorry.There are not any errors,when touch the keyboard it just can't output chinese but English instead.

Comment: The wordlist I converted is just like below,it doesn't look like a valid wordlist. "<w f="789524">prc</w>
<w f="744662">data</w>
<w f="161037">category</w>
<w f="47199">list</w>
<w f="36556">file</w>
<w f="30443">wikipedia</w>
<w f="24719">幵</w>
<w f="23847">jpg</w>
<w f="15783">杈</w>
<w f="12353">小行渟</w>
<w f="11395">日</w>
<w f="8682">hd</w>
<w f="7833">user</w>
<w f="7112">portal</w>
<w f="6814">png</w>
<w f="6803">mediawiki</w>
<w f="5737">zh</w>
<w f="4688">logo</w>
<w f="4576">doc</w>
<w f="4291">of</w>
<w f="4193">小行渟列表</w>
<w f="3705">前</w>
<w f="3257">訸錄</w>"

Answer (score 0):

You can create an android app language pack for AnySoftKeyboard https://github.com/azzamsa/LanguagePack

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the new binary dictionary in the assets/path, and add a similar entry into `res/xml/dictionaries.xml: dictionaryAssertName="dict.mp3"`.

You may find a full example of a language pack here : 
https://github.com/ludovig/vimboard/tree/master/android-vimboard-ask

I'm using AIDE to clone package and build it on my android device.